# Strapi CMS not loading index.html correct path (undefined)

Tags: docker, environment-variables, strapi

Im using Strapi 3.6.8 and i came cross a problem i cant understand with loading the Admin panel.
the CMS status page is working perfect and the API is responding with no problem, but when i try to open the Admin panel i get blank page (white page) and in the page source ican see that there are two files that get 404 error (not found).
The files are: runtime-main.XXXXXXX.js, main.xxxxxxx.chunk.js.
The probplem is clear - the files path is wrong as you can see in the files source:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- The first thing in any HTML file should be the charset -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- Make the page mobile compatible -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <title>Strapi Admin</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- The app hooks into this div -->
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- A lot of magic happens in this file. HtmlWebpackPlugin automatically includes all assets (e.g. bundle.js, main.css) with the correct HTML tags, which is why they are missing in this HTML file. Don't add any assets here! (Check out webpackconfig.js if you want to know more) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/undefined/cms/undefined/admin/runtime~main.1727abc3.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/undefined/cms/undefined/admin/main.be8fb29b.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

unforthantly, i wasn;t able to figure it by myself, i tried the following:

- Checked ENV files
- Cleared yarn/npm lock files and node-module folder (and reinstalled)
- Update packages
- Build and run locally using docker (instead of just runing the server locally)

none of the things i tried is working, im sure it's something really small and stupid to fix. it worked perfeclty until somepoint, but i cant findout what was changed.
Thanks.